# How to verify whether mssql connection in nodejs application is encrypted or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

We know that we can create an encrypted connection in nodejs application with "mssql" package by giving the following configuration.

```
const configDB = {
      server: ServerName,
      user: USER_ID,
      password: pwd,
      database: DatabaseName,
      port: SQL_PORT,
      pool: {
        min: 1,
        max: 10
      },
      options: {
        encrypt: true
      }
    };
```

The encrypt:true option given assures us that connection will be encrypted.But is there any way to verify that connection is encrypted or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this query to check whether the current connection is [encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select encrypt_option
from sys.dm_exec_connections
where session_id = @@spid
```